# Why generic structs cannot be unmanaged?

Tags: c#, c#-7.3

Please look at this code:

```
namespace ConsoleApp
{
    public struct MyPoorGenericStructThatCannotBeUnmanaged<T> where T: unmanaged
    {
        public T Field;
    }

    public class MyClass<T> where T: unmanaged
    {
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // The type 'MyPoorGenericStructThatCannotBeUnmanaged<int>' must be a non-nullable value type, 
            // along with all fields at any level of nesting, 
            // in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'MyClass<T>'
            var obj = new MyClass<MyPoorGenericStructThatCannotBeUnmanaged<int>>(); 
        }
    }
}
```

It fails to compile with error:

> The type 'MyPoorGenericStructThatCannotBeUnmanaged' must be a
>   non-nullable value type, along with all fields at any level of
>   nesting, in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or
>   method 'MyClass'

However `MyPoorGenericStructThatCannotBeUnmanaged<int>` is a non-nullable value type, and all its fields at any value of nesting are non-nullable value types indeed. It is ensured by the generic type constraint  `where T: unmanaged`

Why?

Comment: [Known limitation](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1504). It's being worked on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until the limitation is solved, you can use a workaround based on Unsafe.

This is how the workaround might look like:

```
public unsafe class ArrayOfGenericStructs<TStruct> : IDisposable where TStruct:struct
{
    private void* pointer;

    public ArrayOfGenericStructs(int size)
    {
        pointer = (void*) Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Unsafe.SizeOf<TStruct>() * size);
    }

    public bool IsDisposed { get; private set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (IsDisposed) return;
        IsDisposed = true;
        if (pointer != null) Marshal.FreeHGlobal(new IntPtr(pointer));
        pointer = null;
    }

    public ref TStruct this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return ref Unsafe.AsRef<TStruct>(Unsafe.Add<TStruct>(pointer, index));
        }
    }
}
```